# Интервал между двумя функциями

Tags: javascript, функции

Имеется 2 функции в JS, нужно чтобы вторая выполнялась спустя 1 секунды после выполнения первой. Как реализовать?

```
 function one() {
 //CODE
 }
          // ЗДЕСЬ НУЖЕН ИНТЕРВАЛ

 function two() {
 //CODE
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function callOneAndTwo() {
  one();
  setTimeout(two, 1000);
}
```

> А если три функции поочередно?

```
function callOneTwoAndThree() {
  one();
  setTimeout(function() { 
    two();
    setTimeout(three, 1000);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: А если три функции поочередно? Вот так?

Comment: function callOneAndTwo() {
  one();
  setTimeout(two, 1000); setTimeout(three, 1000);
}