# Не срабатывает setTimeout в js

Tags: javascript, функции, settimeout

Вот этот код в целом не работает.

```js
function headone() {
  document.getElementById("headone").style.opacity = '1';
}

function headtwo() {
  document.getElementById("headtwo").style.opacity = '1';
}

function headthree() {
  document.getElementById("headthree").style.opacity = '1';
}

function head() {
  headone();
  setTimeout(function() {
    headtwo();
    setTimeout(headthree, 1000);
  }, 1000);
}
window.addEventListener("load", headone);
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 0; transition: 4s ease" id="headone">Текст
</div>
<div style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 0; transition: 4s ease" id="headtwo">Текст
</div>
<div style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 0; transition: 4s ease" id="headthree">Текст
</div>
```

Comment: проверь ошибки в консоли

Comment: @Holter так всё же работает в представленном примере...

Comment: Значит у меня с кодом полностью какие-то проблемы. Спасибо всем.

Comment: Надо не  `window.addEventListener("load", headone);` a `window.addEventListener("load", head);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо не

```
window.addEventListener("load", headone);
```

a

```
window.addEventListener("load", head);
```

Молодец, что не сдавался!

---

*Неправильный устаревший ответ:*

На странице нет элемента с `id="headtwo"`.

```js
function headone() {
  document.getElementById("headone").style.opacity = '1';
  console.log("headone");
}

function headtwo() {
  document.getElementById("headtwo").style.opacity = '1';
  console.log("headtwo");
}

function headthree() {
  document.getElementById("headthree").style.opacity = '1';
  console.log("headthree");
}

function head() {
  headone();
  setTimeout(function() {
    headtwo();
    setTimeout(headthree, 1000);
  }, 1000);
}
window.addEventListener("load", head)
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 0; transition: 4s ease" id="headone">Текст One
 </div>
 <div style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 0; transition: 4s ease" id="headtwo">Текст Two
 </div>
 <div style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 0; transition: 4s ease" id="headthree">Текст Three
 </div>
```

Comment: Есть элементы, я уже таким способом пользовался. Сюда я скинул лишь script js, так как ошибка именно где-то здесь.

Comment: Вам в двух ответах продемонстрировали, что подход - рабочий. Хотите, угадаю? В разметке и скрипте буквы "а", "е" или "о" - из разных алфавитов. И еще. Вы, кажется, забыли отметить ответ на вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852308 как принятый.

Comment: @Holter проблема в том, что вы не предоставили в вопросе воспроизводимый пример. Поэтому представленные ответы - из серии "наиболее вероятный вариант".

Comment: @Regent, сезон "не закрываем вопросы, а даем ответы нагаданые на кофейной гуще" объявляется открытым?

Comment: @Igor ни одного принятого ответа в 15 вопросах - это уже не "забыли"...

Comment: @Regent это был намек из серии советов техподдержки "Подуйте в разъем." вместо честного - "Подсоедините монитор к компьютеру." )

Comment: @MedvedevDev вроде ещё есть надежда, что автор поправит вопрос. А вариант с отсутствием элемента с таким ID на странице (при условии что автор не проверял консоль на наличие ошибок) действительно же наиболее вероятен.

Comment: @Regent, ответ - это ответ (внезапно). Это не личная переписка, не вспомогательный вопрос на собеседовании. Не ... ваш вариант. Мне не понять зачем давать ответ на подобные вопросы, когда есть причина "проблему не удается воспроизвести". Отредактировать вопрос добавив элементы и обернув в виджет, оставить об этом коммент, поставил голос за закрытие ... таково мое представление о том, что стоит делать, а не давать мистические ответы на мистические вопросы засоряя информационный поток.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста код в вопросе, только что обновил, вот именно он не работает. Почему?

Comment: @Holter видимо, "О - опечатка"

Answer (score 0):

При наличии на странице элементов с id headone, headtwo, headthree все работает

```js
function headone() {
  document.getElementById("headone").style.opacity = '1';
}

function headtwo() {
  document.getElementById("headtwo").style.opacity = '1';
}

function headthree() {
  document.getElementById("headthree").style.opacity = '1';
}

function head() {
  headone();
  setTimeout(function() {
    headtwo();
    setTimeout(headthree, 1000);
  }, 1000);
}
window.addEventListener("load", head);
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 0; transition: 4s ease" id="headone">Текст
</div>
<div style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 0; transition: 4s ease" id="headtwo">Текст
</div>
<div style="font-size: 33px; opacity: 0; transition: 4s ease" id="headthree">Текст
</div>
```

**Update**

У вас проблема в этой строке

```
window.addEventListener("load", headone);
```

Вы при загрузке страницы вызываете не общую функцию, а функцию отображения первого элемента. Измените ее на

```
window.addEventListener("load", head);
```

и все будет работать

Comment: Добавил разметку в вопрос.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста код в вопросе, вот именно он не работает. Почему?

Comment: @Holter обновил ответ